# Catch waf's run_str output for further processing

Tags: waf

I have a task `something` defined in `waf` which uses `run_str` insted of `def run(self)`.
How can I catch the output (stdout, stderr and returncode) to further process it.

I know I *could* place it all in in `def run(self)`, start the task manually, catch the output and process it. But for the sake of simplicity I would like to keep the `run_str` and do the output processing in an extra function.

actual implementation:

```py
class something(Task.Task):
    run_str = "${PROGRAM} ${ARGS}"
```

So the desired output would be:

```py
class something(Task.Task):
    run_str = "${PROGRAM} ${ARGS}"

    def check_output(self):
       pass
       # stdout, stderr and returncode processing here
```